# tvOS : Force a button to be focused

Tags: objective-c, tvos

I have a `UIView` with a button on it and need to set the focus on the button when the view is added to the `self.view`, but I don't know why the button doesn't focus when the view is added!

```
 - (void)didUpdateFocusInContext:(UIFocusUpdateContext *)context withAnimationCoordinator: (UIFocusAnimationCoordinator *)coordinator {



         if (context.nextFocusedView == backButton) {

             [UIView animateWithDuration:1 delay:0 usingSpringWithDamping:.40 initialSpringVelocity:.60 options:UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction animations:^ {

                 context.nextFocusedView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.5, 1.5);
                 context.nextFocusedView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 10);
                 context.nextFocusedView.layer.shadowOpacity = 1;
                 context.nextFocusedView.layer.shadowRadius = 15;
                 context.nextFocusedView.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
                 context.nextFocusedView.layer.shadowOpacity = 1;

             } completion:nil];


         }

}
```

I also tried other properties :

```
- (void)openView {

        [backButton preferredFocusedView];
        [backButton canBecomeFocused];
        [backButton setNeedsFocusUpdate];

       [self.view addSubView:customView];
}

- (UIView *)preferredFocusedView {

       return [backButton preferredFocusedView];   
}
```

but none of these worked!

Comment: Your question is about tvOS, not iOS or Xcode. Only use relevant tags in a question.

Comment: @rmaddy iOS and Xcode tags have more chance to be viewed !!! than tvOS which has only 200 tags please don't edit my question

Comment: You don't tag a question to get more views. You tag a question so people with the proper knowledge see your question. Your question isn't related to iOS or Xcode. What's the point of using the wrong tags? Sure you might get more views but those extra views are from people that probably don't have the needed knowledge. By your logic you should also add Java and Android tags. That will give you a lot more views too.

Comment: @rmaddy tvOS is basically an iOS and both tvOS and iOS have the same syntax  ,  Xcode the is damn tool I am working with it ! so they are related to each other , instead of give some solution you disturb people ,

Comment: Read the description for the Xcode tag. Your question is not related to the actual use of Xcode. The IDE you are using is irrelevant to your question. And just because iOS and tvOS might have some similarities, they are not the same. BTW - I'm not disturbing anyone. I corrected your tags and you put them back. So I took the time to explain to you how this site works. This is meant be helpful.

Comment: I wonder what this question has to do with Cocoa APIs?

Answer (score 7):

Let's assume you have a UIViewController with a property backButton (a UIButton). This button has been setup properly and is inside the visible bounds of the ViewController's view. It should also have an action defined for the event UIControlEventPrimaryActionTriggered.

If you want the button to be focused when the UIViewController's view is shown, return that button for preferredFocusedView:

```
- (UIView *)preferredFocusedView {
   return self.backButton;
}
```

But if you want it to be focused at a different time in the view lifecycle or user flow, you'd use a different method.

For example, if you want a button to become focused at an arbitrary time: Make sure the button will be returned via the preferredFocusedView, then call setNeedsFocusUpdate on the focus context (in a simple case, the view controller).

Answer (score 4):

This should work.

```
- (UIView *)preferredFocusedView {

       return backButton;   
}
```

Instead of returning [backButton preferredFocusedView], simply return backButton.

Answer (score 0):

You need to return the view you'd like focused from `preferredFocusView` and call `setNeedsFocusUpdate` so the focus system shifts focus to it.